# \input{} File does not exist

Tags: input, python, multiple-files

I have written a template for a personal diary. The main tex file `\input` a file called entries.tex, which will `\input` all the diary entries, which are in a subdirectory, as well as write the title of the entry and the date it is in (both of which it gets from the path and filename)

entries.tex is generated by a python script called entries.py, the output of this script looks like this:

```
\textbf{This is the title}  \hspace*{\fill}  \textbf{2018-11-16}\\
\input{entries/2018/11/16 - This is the title} \bigskip

\textbf{This is another entry}  \hspace*{\fill}  \textbf{2018-11-18}\\
\input{entries/2018/11/18 - This is another entry} \bigskip
```

And the main.tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\title{\huge{}Personal Diary}
\author{\LARGE{}Author name}
\date{Last written \today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage

\input{entries}

\end{document}
```

The directory tree looks like this:

```
Diary
├── entries
│   └── 2018
│       ├── 01
│       ├── 02
│       ├── 03
│       ├── 04
│       ├── 05
│       ├── 06
│       ├── 07
│       ├── 08
│       ├── 09
│       ├── 10
│       ├── 11
│       │   ├── 16 - This is the title.tex
│       │   └── 18 - This is another entry.tex
│       └── 12
├── entries.py
├── entries.tex
├── main.tex
└── makefile
```

However, when I try to compile main.tex, it seems to find entries.tex, but not the files that entries.tex includes. The output of it looks like this:

```
python3 entries.py
pdflatex main.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)  (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
No file main.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./entries.tex

! LaTeX Error: File `entries/2018/11/16 - This is the title.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name:
```

I'm sure that `entries/2018/11/16 - This is the title.tex` exists. Does anyone have any idea why LaTeX wouldn't be finding it?

I have made a github repo with all the code on for anyone who wants to try it out: `https://github.com/ventlion/latexdiary`

Comment: you ask about `\include` but your example code does not use that command, it uses `\input`, but either way it is far simpler if you do not use spaces in file names.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I'll change that now.

Comment: if you really must use spaces then `\input{"entries/2018/11/18 - This is another entry"}` with double quotes but I would not use spaces.

Comment: I have just tried it now, with underscores instead of spaces, and that has fixed the issue. Out of curiosity, what is wrong with using spaces and double quotes when using `\input{}`?

Comment: at the primitive tex syntax level the file input syntax is `\input fooo `  with the filename terminated by a space....   but away from tex spaces in filenames are a pain, in a  bash  shell  try  `ls 16 - This is the title.tex` to see if it lists the filename...

Comment: I see you're point. You'd have to escape the spaces. I may modify my script use underscores instead. Why is it that other LaTeX functions are okay with spaces (such as `\textbf{this is some bold text}`)

Comment: `textbf` doesn't have to access the filesystem using a syntax that works on linux, windows, ibm mainframes, atari, ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the LaTeX 2019-10-01 release onwards explicit `"` quoting is not necessary so

```
    \input{entries/2018/11/18 - This is another entry}
```

will work, but it is still true that it is better to avoid spaces in filenames,

---

The issue is spaces in filenames either use quotes as in

```
\input{"entries/2018/11/18 - This is another entry"}
```

or (usually better) avoid spaces in filenames.

The syntax of filenames is one of the few system dependent parts of TeX but this quote convention is supported by all web2c based distributions (so texlive and miktex in particular).